# Launching an app from within main(). Specify path and filename together or separately?

Tags: java, runtime, exec

From what I understand, the first two statements in the try block should have the same effect; launch chrome.exe, but the first one causes an IO exception because it can't find chrome.exe. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import java.io.File;

public class Program
{
    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {
            try
            {
                //Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chrome.exe", null, new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\"));
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
                process.waitFor();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chrome.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at Program.main(Program.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: OK, I added it. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example change "chrome.exe" to "notepad.exe" as such:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe", null, new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\"));
```

You'll see that this works.  This is because the directory where "notepad.exe" is located is in your Windows Path environment variable.

The problem is that when executing with the `Runtime.exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)` method, you still need to have the executable file being executed in the Path environment variable.  So I went ahead and added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` to my Path and then your code executed as expected.

I think this is a little strange only because I can `cd` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` and execute "chrome.exe" and it works.  So there seems to be an inconsistency here.  In the command prompt in Windows, when I am at a directory (which I presume is the working directory) I can execute the executables in there without having those executables in the Path env variable.  But that is not true when using `Runtime.exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)`.

Comment: Exactly right. I thought I was going crazy! But I intend to use this as part of an application that will run on other peoples' computers and don't think I am allowed to modify the Path environment variable.

Comment: Yes, you did. Thanks for the help.